# Can I designate a block device as the internal storage?

Tags: sd-card, mount, lineageos, 7.1-nougat

Everything was fine as long as I used CyanogenMod 11 (Android 4.4) on my HTC One S. I recently switched to LineageOS 14.1 (Android 7.1.2) and since then couldn't use its non-removable 16-GB sdcard as an internal storage.

Now there is `/storage/emulated/0` instead of it. I logged in via ADB and mounted the card inside this directory (`mount -t vfat -o rw,uid=0,gid=1015 /dev/block/mmcblk0p36 /storage/emulated/0/sdcard`) and could browse it there, but still not on my phone. Permissions are similar for the mounted directory and the rest of the storage.

Any sugestions?

Comment: Is this an office lineage os release or something you found somewhere just on Xda?  Honestly lineage OS is a community effort and is far from perfect.  For example the camera doesn't work at all on mine.  My advice would be work around the issue if you can.

Comment: @William, frankly, it was an unofficial pack of Lineage which I also had to 'fix' manually (remove checks for build time and hboot version). I'm fine with any hack that won't bother me every other day. I just hope Android is as modular and repairable as any normal *nix.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think we can help you to debug problems with a custom ROM you built yourself. This site isn't about ROM development.

Comment: @DanHulme, OK, I reworded it to be more generic. If the answer is "no", I would like to know why.